# mso-page-orientation is not working when I dynamically creating MsWord document using xml

Tags: java, html, css, xml, ms-word

Can somebody tell me why I am unable to genearte document in landscape?

```
<head>
@page Section1
{
    mso-page-orientation:landscape;
    size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:0.25in 0.25in 0.25in 0.25in ;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    mso-footer: f1;
    mso-footer-margin:.25in;
}

div.Section1
{
    page:Section1;
}
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Print</w:View>
<w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>
<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why it isn't working, but maybe this example can help you. I have had issues with this as well and in my case it was a matter of removing inline comments... :s

So I wouldn't be suprised if your problem is the spaces between key and value and before ';'. You do have a section, right? :)

```
<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' 
xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' 
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
<head><title>Microsoft Office HTML Example</title>
<style>
@page
{
    mso-page-orientation: landscape; 
    size:29.7cm 21cm;
    margin:1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm;
}
@page Section1 { }
div.Section1 { page:Section1; }
</style>
<xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Print</w:View>
<w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>
<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml>
</head>
```

Hope it helps!